# Using a single save button for a post request for multiple rows in a Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

So I initially had a save button for each row in the following Datatable.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var table = $('#orderTable').DataTable({


        "columns": [
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            {"orderDataType": "dom-checkbox "},
            {"orderDataType": "dom-select disabled"}
        ]});
        /* Create an array with the values of all the checkboxes in a column */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-checkbox'] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return $('input', td).prop('checked') ? '1' : '0';
        } );
    }

    /* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
    {
        return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
            return $('select', td).val();
        } );
    }
```

I have an edit function that enables me to save the changes made to the data in those two columns by a user

```
        $(document).on('click','#Edit', function() {


        var myTable;
        myTable = $('#orderTable').DataTable();
        myTable.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {

            var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');


            var jsonReturnObj = new Object();
            jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber = thisRow.find("td").eq(0).text();
            jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber = thisRow.find("td").eq(1).text();
            //jsonReturnObj.processed = thisRow.find("td").eq(11).find(":checkbox").is(':checked');
            jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode = thisRow.find("td").eq(15).find("option:selected").prop("value");
            if (jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode != "" && jsonReturnObj.RejectReasonCode != null) {
                jsonReturnObj.Processed = true;

            } else {
                jsonReturnObj.Processed = false;

            }

            //jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = $("#movedInput"+jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber+"-"+jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber).is(':checked');
            if ($("#movedInput" + jsonReturnObj.OrderNumber + "-" + jsonReturnObj.OrderLineNumber).is(':checked')) {
                jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = false;
            } else {
                jsonReturnObj.IsAvailable = true;
            }
            var jsonReturnString = JSON.stringify(jsonReturnObj);

            //$('#orderReportTable').append(jsonReturnString);

            //var position = table.fnGetPosition(this);

            var request2 = $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'RejectingStoreNum': thisRow.find("td").eq(12).text(),
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                type: "POST",

                url: "persistStoreResearchOutcome", 
                data: jsonReturnString,//json data. use data and contentType attributes for POST requests.
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "text",
                /*xhrFields: {
                'withCredentials': true //Tell browser to provide credentials
            },*/
                crossDomain: true,// this is for cross domain requests*/
                success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                    console.log("status:" + status);
                    $('#orderReportTable').append("call successful");
                    if (jsonReturnObj.Processed) {
                        thisRow.find("td").eq(13).text("Researched");
                        table.draw();
                    } else {
                        //alert("please select a research outcome for this item");
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                    //console.log("failed: status:"+status);
                    $('#orderReportTable').append("call failed, error" + errorThrown);
                    alert("There was an error while trying to save this item");
                }

            });

        });
    });

});
```

I tried adding a loop to the edit function but it keeps throwing the alert - There was an error while trying to save this item.
Can someone help me understand how can I convert this -  a  single save button for each row to a bulk update save button for all rows?